# How to make select with variable using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a Google sheet with several columns, where are recorded support requests from clients.

```
     A                B                      C
-+---------------+------------------------+-------------
1| Date-1        | John                   | Ticket-101 
2| Date-1        | Anita                  | Ticket-102
3| Date-2        | John                   | Ticket-103
4| Date-3        | Dani                   | Ticket-104
5| Date-3        | Billy                  | Ticket-105
```

I want to create two new columns with statistical data about the clients. In these new columns, I want to have the client name and number of opened support tickets.

The end result must be:

```
     A                B             C            D          E
-+---------------+------------+-------------+-----------+---------------
1| Date-1        | John       | Ticket-101  | John      |   2    |
2| Date-1        | Anita      | Ticket-102  | Anita     |   1    |
3| Date-2        | John       | Ticket-103  | Dani      |   1    |
4| Date-3        | Dani       | Ticket-104  | Billy     |   1    |
5| Date-3        | Billy      | Ticket-105  |
```

I created the **D column** in this way:

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(B1:B))
```

For counting how many times the client contact us I use:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(B1:B, "select B where B='John'", 0)))
```

Of course, this is a very stupid solution, because for every new client I must to create a new formula with

> ....where B='Client name'".....

I'm wondering is it possible to create a formula in a way in which the name of the client is automatically populated? I imagine something like that:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY(B1:B, "select B where B='value-of-D'", 0))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(B:C, 
 "select B,count(C) 
  where B!='' 
  group by B 
  label count(C)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

also you can order it like:

```
=QUERY(B:C, 
 "select B,count(C) 
  where B!='' 
  group by B 
  order by count(C) desc
  label count(C)''", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you player0 and @JPV

The both solution works in the same way, but there is another problem I had no idea. The results are in alphabetical order by client names. 

I have additional columns F, G, H where have to write additional information manually. For example notes.

That's why after every new ticket, the pairs "Client name: count" float up/down, depending on the name of the client submitted a new ticket.

I want the name of clients to stay statistically, where the new names to be added at the bottom of the list.

Do you have ideas on how we can solve that?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here you are the example sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lH8cMnfU6L3vVdXk2VoSR0I1943tGIHJlQHj-_5GZTo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B2:B), QUERY(B2:C, 
 "select B,count(C) 
  where B!='' 
  group by B 
  label count(C)''", 0), {1,2}, 0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(B:C, "Select B, count(C) where B<>'' group by B label B 'Name', count(C) 'Count'", 1)
```

and see if that works?